# How to select results from multiple records and tables into one row

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, oracle11g

I have a characteristics table with multiple codes and values for an ID, and a lookup table that has the corresponding description for each code and value.  I want to select a ID, descr1, descr2 from the two tables where the first descr is for one lookup code/value pair, and descr is for another.  For example:

```
Table1
ID   Code    Value
1    Color   1
1    Tone    4
1    Type    Poor
2    Color   3
2    Tone    4


Table2
Code   Value  Descr
Color  1      Red
Color  2      Blue
Color  3      Yellow
Tone   4      Clear
Type   Good   Used, but good condition
Type   New    New
Type   Poor   Used, poor condition
```

I want to be able to query for ID 1 and get the color and type, and so get a record like

```
ID   Color   Type
1    Red     Used, poor condition
```

I can get one of those, but I'm failing at getting the second in the same row

```
select t1.ID, t2.Descr as Color
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2
  on t1.Code = t2.Code
 and t1.Value = t2.Value
where t1.ID = 1
and t1.Code = (select t2b.Code
                 from Table2 t2b
                where t1.Code = t2b.Code
                  and t1.Value = t2b.Value
                  and t1.Value = 'Color')
```

I think I'm going about it all wrong, and I've been looking -- I'm SURE this question is already asked, but I'm not finding it.  Sometimes, you need to know the words used in the type of query to be able to find help on what you're trying to do.

**Update**
I combined the answers from GKV and knagaev, because the max and the case together gave me what I was looking for.  This gave me what I wanted:

```
select t1.ID
      ,max((case when t1.Code='Color' then t2.Descr else null end)) as Color
      ,max((case when t1.Code='Type' then t2.Descr else null end)) as Type
from Table1 t1,Table2 t2
where t1.Code = t2.Code and t1.Value = t2.Value
  and   t1.ID = 1
group by t1.ID
```

Comment: So, what do I do when I needed to combine two answers to get the solution?  Whose answer to I select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only "standard" oracle SQL

```
select t1.id,
  max(decode (t1.code, 'Color', t2.descr, null)) color,
  max(decode (t1.code, 'Tone', t2.descr, null)) tone,
  max(decode (t1.code, 'Type', t2.descr, null)) type
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.code = t2.code
  and t1.value = t2.value
  and t1.id = 1
group by t1.id
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f016e/3)

Answer (score 4):

Just simple join will do the job along with string concatenation.
somewhat like this

```
  select t1.ID
    ,wm_concat(case when t1.Code='Color' then t2.Descr else null end) as Color
    ,wm_concat(case when t1.Code='Type' then t2.Descr else null end) as Type
    from Table1 t1,Table2 t2
    where t1.Code = t2.Code and t1.Value = t2.Value
      and   t1.ID = 1
    group by t1.ID
```

Comment: wm_concat is undocumented. OP should use listagg on 11g instead

Comment: I didn't want the fields combined, I just wanted to get them in one record.  So wm_concat or listagg are unnecessary.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek
i just used string concatenation as 
null + string =string...this was my idea  behind writing string concatenation ...

Comment: Oh, I see.  I'll go back and play with that some more.